# Limiting Submission of a Certain Field on a CloudPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have a CloudPage being used to collect appointments for a meeting time. I have one CloudPage, and five time slots mapping back to data extension, specifically to the field "Time." "Time" is a text field appearing as a radio button on the form itself.

Can I limit the submissions for each time option? I am familiar with the option to block off the whole CloudPage after it reaches a certain threshold.

I tried the AMPscript below, but I am trying to wrap it around each field instead of the whole form so only *that* time field is taken off the page upon reaching capacity. I get an error when trying to publish the CloudPage.

```
%%[

SET @rows = LookupRows("AMPSCRIPT", "Time", 2:15pm))

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

IF @rowCount < 2 THEN

]%%

  <p>sorry maximum has been met</p>

%%[ ELSE ]%%

--field--

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Is this even possible? Where am I going wrong in the AMPscript?

Comment: It would help if you share the error.

Comment: In first analysis, your lookup contains an extra parenthesis.

Comment: Hello @FrançoisPerret, thanks for reaching out. 

The error I get is that, when I try to publish the CloudPage, the page shows the "sorry maximum has been met" message for the field I wrapped the AMPscript  around, even when that particular attribute hasn't surpassed 2 submissions in the DE: https://mc0kpjdtspm-db0wqphgtrbqr5l4.pub.sfmc-content.com/rtymflq4e3x

Comment: That makes sense : the message "sorry ..." is displayed when there are 0 or 1 row returned (<2). Try with IF @rowCount ›= 2 THEN ...

Comment: @FrançoisPerret Thank you! I got so caught up in the AMPscript, I didn't notice this glaring error. This works now. Many thanks to you.

Comment: great  If your problem is solved, please consider accepting ✔️ my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
%%[
  SET @rows = LookupRows("AMPSCRIPT", "Time", 2:15pm))
  SET @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
  IF @rowCount >= 2 THEN
]%%
  <p>sorry maximum has been met</p>
%%[ ELSE ]%%
  --field--
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: I would also add a validation in form handler, to check if anyone else submitted a record between the time the form was generated and the time it was submitted.